# Different appearance of same website on localhost and remote server using Safari for iPhone iOS 7

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, web, nginx

I use `Pure CSS` to make my website responsive, but when this site runs on my own computer, it looks fine:

[image]

But after I uploaded it to my remote server, it's like too far from right border of the window:

[image]

I've debugged the site on both servers with iPhone Safari remote debugger, I'm sure every CSS and Javascript source was loaded correctly. Here's my index.html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="martianblog">
<head>
<title>{{.Title}}|{{.Subtitle}}</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.staticfile.org/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.staticfile.org/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/lib/notification.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.staticfile.org/highlight.js/7.4/styles/monokai_sublime.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
<div notifications="bottom right"></div>
<div class="pure-u-1" ui-view></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.staticfile.org/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/lib/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.staticfile.org/marked/0.2.9/marked.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.staticfile.org/angular.js/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/lib/angular-sanitize.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.staticfile.org/angular-ui-router/0.2.0/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/filters.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/directives.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/lib/notification.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my custom css file's [link](http://blog.duyizhuo.com/static/css/custom.css)

My computer's system: **Mac OS X Mavericks**

My remote server's system: **Ubuntu 12.04 GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-virtual i686**

Nginx version on my remote server: **nginx/1.1.19**

Comment: provide a fiddle to get answers quickly

Comment: @San My project could be huge and complicated that I don't know how to deal with it :(

Comment: it can be anything. hard to help you here...sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, very difficult to suggest anything without at least a link to your css file(s).

Some things to check: html doctype declaration, browser cache, file encoding types, any fixed widths that may have been set in your CSS....... Perhaps you have uploaded a file that has a capital letter in its filename? May not be an issue locally, but could be an issue on your server.

edit: I have checked out your site and it looks full width to me, are you sure you have fully cleared your cache?

Your viewport is currently set to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0>
```

Perhaps this should be:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Are you using Safari on iPhone 5 with iOS 7?

Comment: I have justed tested from an ipad. I will retest from an iphone with iOS7. Waiting for it to charge - shouldn't be too long.

Comment: Looking more closely at your viewport tag, you have your quotes in the wrong place maybe and also missing a comma?

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: Hi, I have modified my answer above to show the correct viewport tag. Maybe that is the problem?